# deleting table records in SQL server 2005 database and keep the deleted records

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I am using asp.NET C# and I have a table in SQL server 2005 database. Once a student clicks a specific button in the application interface, the student id that will be taken from the session should be stored in the StudentID attribute. At a specific time (for example: at 9:00 A.M) I want to delete the table records automatically. It will be better if I could be able to archive these deleted records somewhere. 
I searched in Google and I found that I have to make a log trigger, but I am not sure if it will be the best solution in my situation where I want to delete the table records twice a day (in two different hours)!!

Actually I never use the trigger but I read that it used to delete records in someway.

Any help regarding deleting the table records in SQL server 2005 database will be appreciated..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A regular SQL trigger should work fine:

```
create trigger FooDeleteTrigger on Foo
after delete
as
insert FooArchive (...columns...)
select ...columns...
from deleted
```

Alternatively, all in one command:

```
delete from Foo
output deleted.col1, deleted.col2, ...
into FooArchive
--where clause as needed, etc
```

Comment: I am not sure which better to use? trigger or store procedure? I have no experience in both. so please help me deciding..

Comment: @user3287580 either will work fine, although I didn't actually mention stored procedures at any point

Answer (score 1):

Write a stored procedure to delete the records from the table and in the same SP write statements to insert the deleted record in your archive table. You can use *deleted* keyword to access the deleted rows from the table. Now once you are done writing the SP create a job in SQL Server on this SP and schedule it as per your requirement.

Alternatively you can only put the deletion logic in the stored procedure and move the insertion-to-archive-table logic to trigger developed on the main table.

Check this out for your reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: It isn't clear that creating a stored procedure is adding much here

Comment: @MarcGravell yes you are right it can be done without creating SP. As per my opinion creating a SQL job will be more maintainable with a SP as it also adds re-usability (same SP can be used for one or more sql server job).

Comment: It seems the requirement is to delete and archive the data periodically. As per my opinion, to address the requirement, sql job should be best fit.